# Получение списка схем на сервере Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Создаю подключение к серверу оракла (успешно).

```
string oracleDbConnection = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                                                        + "(ADDRESS_LIST="
                                                                + "(ADDRESS="
                                                               + "(PROTOCOL=TCP)"
                                                               + "(HOST=111.111.11.111)" \\ Здесь написал фейковый адрес
                                                               + "(PORT=1521)"
                                                               + ")"
                                                       + ")"
                                                        + "(CONNECT_DATA="
                                                                + "(SERVER=DEDICATED)"
                                                                + "(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)"
                                                        + ")"
                                                 + ");"
        + "User Id=test;Password=test;";

        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleDbConnection);
```

далее хотел посмотреть все схемы (получить их имена, и в будущем другие параметры)

```
connection.Open();
            OracleCommand cursCmd = new OracleCommand("select * from all_users", connection);
            OracleDataReader reader = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Сделал ли всё правильно, господа, и как дальше получить список схем?

В строке подключения соединение происходит через главную схему test. Как мне объяснили, через неё можно получить сведения о всех остальных схемах на сервере.

В идеале, надо получить список схем, в которые приложение будет заливать дампы.

Comment: Ну как бы все правильно с виду. в представлении `all_users` действительно список всех пользователей. А в оракле пользователь=схема. А дальше ... видимо читать из полученного курсора строки как и при любом другом селекте

Comment: _"получить сведения о всех остальных схемах"_ -- какие схемы нужны? если таблицы, то так `var tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");`

Comment: Наверно не совсем. На сервере примерно 30 схем на каждую из которой можно накатывать дампы приложения. Каждая схема, соответственно, содержит свои таблицы

Comment: список схем для oracle - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc716723(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Stack В Oracle _схема_ называется только одно, то же самое, что "база данных" в mysql, например. И схема содержит таблицы

Comment: @Дмитрий Я думаю вам больше подойдет что то типа `select distinct owner from all_tables where table_name='xxx'` где xxx имя какой нибудь таблицы которая присутствует на всех интересующих схемах. Иначе вы получите кучу "лишних" схем типа SYS, SYSTEM и т.п. которые в вашей задаче скорее всего не нужны

Comment: @Дмитрий главное что из all_tables вы получите только то, на что у вашего пользователя есть права, хотя бы на чтение. Иначе как вы будете что то "накатывать", если прав нет ...

Comment: select distinct owner from all_tables where table_name='SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION" (уже вставил имя таблицы) - это вместо запроса select * from all_users  ? Если да, то странно, не получается что-то. Получаю исключение при точке останова на OracleDataReader reader = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: @Дмитрий ну это уже не ко мне :) я оракл знаю, а с c# не сталкивался. В общем чтение по такому запросу должно дать правильный результат. Можете проверить в каком нибудь sqlplus просто под своим пользователем. заодно убедитесь что коннект к базе вообще проходит

Comment: Да, попробую. Спасибо Mike, что отозвались.)

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @Дмитрий Что нибудь получилось ? А то видите, Николас предлагает ответом сделать, а я понимаю что инфа полезна, но является ли она ответом ...

Comment: Да, благодаря Mike-у получилось!) Ошибку исправил. Теперь буду ковыряться, пробовать написать запрос, чтобы по каждой схеме показывало сколько места она занимает на момент запроса. Но это так, к слову)... Спасибо stackoverflow! Первый раз воспользовался вашим сайтом и не ожидал такого живого участия!

Comment: @Дмитрий ну в интернете предлагают select owner,sum(bytes) from dba_segments group by owner. НО все таблицы dba_ доступны только пользователям с правами DBA, т.е. админам базы. Можно конечно обойтись выдачей прав на select только для данной таблицы вашему пользователю

Comment: угу, нашёл вот ещё интересный вариант - http://mirsovetov.net/oracle-schema-size.html - третий запрос в статье

Answer (score 1):

`select * from all_users` даст список всех пользователей (схем) на сервере Oracle, включая кучу системных.

Для получения списка схем на которых есть таблицы, доступные пользователю, под которым вы подключились лучше использовать представление `all_tables`. И лучше дополнительно ограничить список, например найдя схемы в которых содержится конкретная таблица:

```
select owner from all_tables where table_name='xxx'
```